# Using Matplotlib to create a simple schedule

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple schedule using Matplotlib. I have the following start. I want to remove the y-axis numbers and display "a=1", "a=2", "a=3" instead. Indeed, `y1` and `y2` defined in my function are sort of fake because the thickness of the box does not really have to be some number. As long as I have an equal thickness for each "a," it is all fine. I want to plot a box with a shade for a=1 in between 370 and 560, for a=2 in between 550 and 980 and so on. The x-axis shows the time in minutes. I checked horizontal bar plots, but they all start from 0 and I couldn't figure out a way to convert them into a scheduling type. Any suggestions?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =  [(370, 560), (550,980), (380,440)]

def activity_filler(x,y1,y2):
    # Shade the area between y1 and y2
    plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2,
                     facecolor="grey", # The fill color
                     color='grey',       # The outline color
                     alpha=0.4, hatch = 'X\/|-')          # Transparency of the fill
activity_filler(x[0],[1],[2])
activity_filler(x[1],[2],[3])
activity_filler(x[2],[3],[4])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [(370, 560), (550,980), (380,440)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,evt in enumerate(x):
    ax.barh(i,width=evt[1]-evt[0],left=evt[0])

ax.set_yticks(range(len(x)))
ax.set_yticklabels([f'a={i+1}' for i in range(len(x))])
```

[image]